# How to read a specific line in a text file and return a part of it?

Tags: java, parsing, text, bufferedreader

I have several strings in a file where I am supposed to stop and read the values from those strings. For example:

```
This is the first line
#1 stop = 300
This is the third line
This is the 4th line
#2 stop = 400
This is the 6th line
```

I need to stop at #1 and extract the value 300 from there. Then I have to stop at #2 and extract 400, and so on.

I am VERY new to Java and can't figure out what is wrong with my code. (I haven't gotten to extracting the values yet):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        //read
        File fromFile = new File("in.txt");         
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile));
        String line;
        String firstHandler="";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { 
            bufferedReader.readLine();       
            if (firstHandler.startsWith("#1")){
                System.out.println(firstHandler);
                String[] parts = firstHandler.split("=");   
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));  
             } 
                 break;
        }

        System.out.println(line);
         bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

At this point it only prints the first line, which is not at all what I need. Can anyone explain to me how this should be done in the right way?

Comment: You need to generalize your pattern a bit more. Instead of only looking for #1 you'll need to be able to look for any number after the #

Comment: ' if (firstHandler.startsWith("#1")){ ' looks incorrect for your purpouse instead use the delimiter "#" so your code should look like this ' if (firstHandler.startsWith("#")){ '

Comment: You don't specify an encoding when opening the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as pointed out in the comments, you need to match lines starting with a #, since there are multiple lines beginning with # but having a different second character.

Next, you need to check the value of the line that you are reading to check for the # character. So, you can get rid of the `firstHandler` variable and use the `line` variable instead.

Finally, you need to get rid of the `break` statement, since that causes the loop to exit after the first line itself. That is the reason you only see the first line on the screen.

Therefore, your code can be changed to something like this:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {                
         if (line.startsWith("#"))
           {
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] parts = line.split("=");   
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));  
           } 
         }
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to split the string into array to return the "300" value or is there another, better way?

Comment: If your lines started only with # and followed the same format, you could have just taken the substring at index where the "300" text appears. But since it looks like the lines could start with anything from"#1" to #1000" or perhaps more, it is better to use the split method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it's clearer to me.

Answer (score 3):

The errors are in these 4 lines:

```
    String firstHandler="";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { 
        bufferedReader.readLine();      
        if (firstHandler.startsWith("#1")){
```

You read one line from inside the `while` statement. And for each line read, you enter the block. But inside this block, you read yet another line.

And then, what you compare with `"#1"` is not the line that you have just read, but `firstHandler`, which is initialized as an empty string once, and never modified. The code should be:

```
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { 
        if (line.startsWith("#1")) {
```

The `reader` should also be closed in a `finally` block, but that's another matter.

Comment: awesome...big fan of your explanations for a while now...+1!! :)

Comment: I think that there is also a problem with the delimiter it should be "#" instead of "#1" because "#1" would only read the first line

Comment: oh @NoobEditor Got that +1 :)

Comment: @JB Nizet `if (line.startsWith("#1"))` makes sense, thank you. However, it still reads the first line only. How can I make it read the other lines as well, so that it can reach #1?

Comment: Sorted the delimiter problem out

Comment: That has been answered in comments and other answers. Use line.startsWith("#") instead. And don't use `break`, since that will end the loop as soon as you have met the first line starting with #.

Comment: @Ayvadia I will also have other types of symbols for the lines I'll have to return, besides #1 and #2 I can have `(word)` or `!word`

Comment: @nanachan I would use regex in that case, if all(your lines) start with # then you can use the # without a number appended. If however the line starts with many different characters, google regex and read the javadocs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)